# Can we visualize pressure drop regions too in blender ? ( In fluid simulation )

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, workflow, fluid-simulation

Is there any possible way to have a look at pressure drop regions too in Blender Fluid simulation ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple force field for that (of course you should not use so high strength as i did here:

[image]